# How to add gif image to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gif

I am trying to link a visualization to Jupyter notebook using iframe and JS scripts provided from the site: https://public.flourish.studio/visualisation/1631776/ but getting invalid syntax error in notebook.

I have tried as below, any ideas on what is the issue?

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
js = "<div class="flourish-embed flourish-bar-chart-race" data-src="visualisation/1631776"> 
<script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>"
display(HTML(js))
```

**ERROR:**

```
File "<ipython-input-4-5d8ce592337a>", line 2
js = "<div class="flourish-embed flourish-bar-chart-race" data-src="visualisation/1631776"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>"
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

***Note:*** I also tried loading the same gif from git repo as below, but got a timeout error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread("https://github.com/rsyed1/kaggle/blob/master/Cases2020.gif?raw=true")
plt.imshow(img)
```

**Error:**

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1317                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following for the iframe:

```py
import IPython
url = "https://public.flourish.studio/visualisation/1631776/"
iframe = '<iframe src=' + url + ' width=700 height=350></iframe>'
IPython.display.HTML(iframe)
```

Ignore the warning as the version it suggests presently doesn't work.

---

For using code to display the gif:

```py
from IPython.display import Image
Image("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rsyed1/kaggle/master/Cases2020.gif")
```

---

For placing your gif image in a **markdown cell**, use:

```
![display image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rsyed1/kaggle/master/Cases2020.gif)
```